# How to Organize My Dart Project

Tags: dart

I'm getting to the point in my Dart project where I need to start putting things in separate files/packages. My project has 2 generic areas of concern, so it seems like there needs to be 2 libraries, call them libA and libB, and then some generic code that draws on both of them. Ideally, I need something between one file and full-on separate projects.

I don't think I'm ever gonna want to export them as separate Pubs, but maybe... Does that mean they should be libraries and not packages? Is there even a difference between libraries and packages in Dart? Do I need 3 different full projects? I hope not.

I guess I'm looking for a way to have several local packages in the same project.

What's the SIMPLEST way to structure everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code will only be relevant to one project, use one package and multiple libraries. For instance, consider a tower defense game: there will be one package for the whole game, but multiple libraries each dealing with their own areas of concern (enemy lib, tower lib, etc.).

If your code will be relevant to multiple projects but only for your projects (and not the general public), split the code into multiple packages, use local or github pub dependencies, and do not publish them on Pub:

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    path: /Users/me/transmogrify
```

See [Pub Dependencies](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html) for more info.

Continuing the above tower defense example, this would be useful for something like a game studio splash/intro screen. You would want to reuse this across multiple games, but it is not useful for anyone but you.

Finally, if the code can be used for multiple projects, and is of interest to other developers, publish it as a Pub package. For instance, a game engine would be useful to other game developers.

Comment: Sounds good. Can you direct me to some examples of the first two options. I'm mostly confused about folder structure and what the import statements look like.

Comment: http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html is a good read. For a great example of multiple internal libraries check out https://github.com/dart-lang/pop-pop-win/tree/master/lib.